# Use HTTPS for Marketing cloud microsite

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssl, microsites

We have built microsite **page.mycompany.com**, when we try to access this site using HTTPS we get error for certificate **net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID**
The certificate is issued for ***.s6.exacttaget.com**

Answer (score 1):

Personalized URLs are not HTTPS unless you work with SFMC to configure an SSL certificate.

You can, however, use the base SFMC landing page URL with HTTPS --  with the same `QS` parameter:

```
https://pages.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=YOURPAGESPARAMETERHERE
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam-Springs , contacted SMC support and account exec.

Comment: Hi @Adam-Springs - where would I obtain the query string parameter?

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem too - we had to contact our account manager to purchase new SSL certificates, and also get the option to create HTTPS:// pages in CloudPages activated on our account (it is not available by default).

Answer (score -1):

At first, try using in URL as "https://page.mycompany.com", it will asking for validation of certificate still it should take you to your site. Moreover if you enter the [Certificate](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_keys_uploading_signed_cert.htm&language=en_US) in Certificate and Key management signed by one of the trusted CA provider by salesforce into the domain created in salesforce then , salesforce will authenticate your microsite and take you to that page.

Comment: I believe that is specific to Salesforce core, not Marketing Cloud.  For Marketing Cloud, if an SSL certificate needs to be configured for the private domain being used for the account then an additional purchase is required.  A client can contact their AE in order to get this.